# Does dart2js optimize const objects better?

Tags: javascript, dart, dart2js

Are class instances created with a `const` constructor more optimized than the normal instances (created with a `new` constructor) when compiled to JavaScript with dart2js?

Answer (score 2):

Here is 2 tuple implementations:

With a constant constructor:

```dart
class Tuple{
  final _1, _2;
  foo()=> _1 + _2;
  const Tuple(this._1,this._2);
}

void main() {
  var a = const Tuple(10,20);
  var b = const Tuple(10,20);
  print(a);
  print(b);
  print(a.foo());
}
```

With a new constructor:

```dart
class Tuple{
  final _1, _2;
  foo()=> _1 + _2;
  Tuple(this._1,this._2);
}
void main() {
  var a = new Tuple(10,20);
  var b = new Tuple(10,20);
  print(a);
  print(b);
  print(a.foo());
}
```

[dart2js outputs comparison](http://www.diffnow.com/?report=3mizq)

That is how `new Tuple` looks in the output:

```dart
main: function() {
    P.print(new S.Tuple(10, 20));
    P.print(new S.Tuple(10, 20));
    P.print(30);
}
```

`const Tuple` is created only once `C.Tuple_10_20 = new S.Tuple(10, 20);` and used like this:

```dart
main: function() {
    P.print(C.Tuple_10_20);
    P.print(C.Tuple_10_20);
    P.print(C.Tuple_10_20._1 + C.Tuple_10_20._2);
}
```

Note that in the case of `new Tuple` the function call has been replaced with its return value literal but it didn't happen for the `const Tuple` output.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the diff in your answer; your link is set to expire in one year.

Comment: That's something we (dart2js-team) should fix. Const-objects should always be at least as good as non-const objects.