# Can someone illustrate how to use const constructor, and under what circumstances do I need to use it?

Tags: dart

I've just started to learn dart, but I can't understand const constructor. Can someone illustrate how to use const constructor.

Under what circumstances do I need to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Const objects are used in annotations:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Foo{
  final name;
  const Foo(this.name);
}
@Foo("Bar")
class Baz{}
void main() {
  ClassMirror cm = reflectClass(Baz);
  print(cm.metadata.first.getField(#name).reflectee); // prints Bar
}
```

Why const objects were introduced(from the dev team):
 [Why does Dart have compile time constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418819/why-does-dart-have-compile-time-constants)

Also they can provide extra optimization. For example, my dar2js experiment:
 [Does dart2js optimize const objects better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771831/does-dart2js-optimize-const-objects-better)

Some specifics:

```dart
class Foo{
  final baz;
  const Foo(this.baz);
}

void main() {
//var foo = const Foo({"a" : 42}); //error {"a" : 42} is a mutable Map
  var foo = const Foo(const {"a" : 42}); //ok
//foo.baz["a"] = 1; //error Cannot set value in unmodifiable Map
  var bar = new Foo({"a" : 42}); //ok
//bar.baz = {"c" : 24}; //error NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'baz='
  bar.baz["a"] = 1; //ok;
}
```

If class has only const constructor you still can create mutable object with `new`
`final baz` is immutable reference. But since `bar` is mutable, you can change `baz` object.

Answer (score 2):

Did you happen to stumble upon Chris Strom's [post about constant constructors](http://japhr.blogspot.com/2012/12/dart-constant-constructors.html)? What Chris Strom does in the article is an explanation of final fields, but scroll down to the comments section and there's a nice clarification of constant constructors from a certain Lasse.